# Using INDEX and MATCH, IF and AND to return the column title of a cell Excel 2011 Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

[enter image description here][1]I have a data set consisting of columns representing 0.1 metre increments, and for each column I have a numerical value. These numerical values decrease as the distance (column titles) increases.

I wish to find the cell where value is greater than 10 and the adjacent cell has a value of less than 10, and return the corresponding column title (i.e. the distance value).

I have been attempting this using `=INDEX(C$32:ZE$32,MATCH(,C32:ZE32,0))`

However, I am unsure how to proceed. I assume I have to use `IF` and `AND` in the `MATCH` parentheses but that's as far as I can get.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot to clarify how your data looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the values decrease as the distance increases. That means that all you need to do is find the last value that is greater than 10 and it is guaranteed that the cell to the right of it is less than 10. You can use `MATCH` to do that if you specify `-1` as the third parameter.

```
=INDEX(C32:ZE32,MATCH(10,C33:ZE33,-1))
```

[image]

You didn't say what should happen if one of the values is **exactly** 10. The above formula finds the last value that is greater than or equal to 10. If you want to find that last value that is greater than but **not** equal to 10, you could use this formula:

```
=INDEX(C32:ZE32,COUNTIF(C33:ZE33,">10"))
```